# change cmake compiler from clang to g++ for mac

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, compiler-errors, cmake

I am working with a very inconvenient software, and it doesn't support clang. So, I am required to change my cmake compiler and as I read almost everywhere, and here [How can I make CMake use GCC instead of Clang on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380456/how-can-i-make-cmake-use-gcc-instead-of-clang-on-mac-os-x), I tried :

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++
```

However, I am still getting this error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:59 (message):
```

`GAMBIT does not support the Clang compiler.  Please choose another
  compiler.`

`-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`

Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Use `cmake-gui` and change the settings there?

Comment: Try setting both the C and C++ compilers in the CMakeLists.txt file: SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /path/to/c/compiler)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /path/to/cpp/compiler)

Comment: Check if you have *real* gcc installed. AFAIR Xcode no longer ships *gcc*, and running `gcc` invokes `clang`.

Comment: `g++ --version` should remove any confusion.

Comment: I had two g++ one /usr/bin/g++ which was symlink of clang and the other one was /opt/local/bin/g++ which was my installed g++!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found setting environment variables `CC` and `CXX` before running CMake for the first time peferrable to messing with `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. Also note that it's probably a good idea to set both. So get into an empty binary directory and run this:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc CXX=/usr/bin/g++ cmake ...
```

Also make sure that `/usr/bin/gcc` is really GCC and not e.g. a symlinked or otherwise disguised Clang (I believe such [setup](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/40374) can exist in the MacOS world).

Comment: Also, relevant is that /usr/bin/gcc may not be gcc in the questioner's environment...

Comment: @JeffGarrett I've edited the answer, but my dev life and Apple do not intersect at all; can you please check that I've captured the concern correctly?

Comment: I don't have my MBP nearby. The following even claims it might be clang but not-a-symlink: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663695/mac-os-x-usr-bin-gcc-file

Comment: A comment here describes it as a clang shim: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/40374

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` as well, that is:

`cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc`

Indeed, looking at Gambit source code, it seems it's mostly C.

Personally, I usually like to set both, just in case.

Comment: my /usr/bin/g++ was actually a symlink to clang and the real address for my g++ was /opt/local/bin/g++! the default /usr/bin/g++ is the one coming with xcode